# jsonp query from a newbie

Tags: php, jquery, jsonp

I am a bit new to this and trying to get my head around this. On a server I have the following code:

```
<?php
    require_once("../includes/smplPDO.php");
    $db = new smplPDO();
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT establishment.Category_id, categories.category FROM establishment INNER JOIN categories ON establishment.Category_id = categories.id WHERE establishment.Town_id = $id AND establishment.active = 1 AND establishment.Category_id <> 27 ORDER BY categories.category ASC";
    $arr = $db->run($sql)->fetchAll();
    $arr['name'] = "response";
    echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($arr).");";
?>
```

This will return an array (`$arr`) of 24 items - `category_id` and `category` (each something like: `1, Bars and Clubs`). On my other server (local for the moment) I have the following

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "the appropriate URL",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(cats){
        alert("Success");
        $("#result1").html(JSON.stringify(cats));
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Error");
    } 
});
```

I get the success message but I am having trouble with the content of the div which initially I want to see what is returned. At the moment I am getting an output of

```
{"name":"response"}
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated. In the ideal world I would output each of the items in the returned array.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `$("#result1").html(cats.name);` instead of re-serialising the already deserialised object.

Comment: did you pass the data ? id and callback ?

Comment: The problem might be your SQL-query. Have you checked, if it actually returns something? ``$arr`` seems to be empty before you add the 'name' property.

Comment: Rory I changed the line as you suggest and the output was "response".

Comment: Mohammed I have passed the parameter.

Comment: Guido I  have checked the size of the array and it is 24

Comment: Mohammed I am a little confused about passing the callback. Can you give me guidance please?

Comment: I have limited php knowledge, but shouldn't it be `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: I am using a class which simplifies pdo

Comment: It might help if you expand your post and provide an example of the expected data that PHP is sending back. Also, you should be able to see the RAW response in your browsers console. Another helpful tool is `condole.log()`, this will write a string into your console for review. So you could add to your success: `console.log(cats);` and this will show you what the browser is receiving.

Comment: Where should I add console.log(cats); ?

Comment: The client has agreed that I can give you the url which is url:      "http://www.gayguideworld.com/api/index.php?id=16"

Comment: I have solved this. Thanks to everyone.